# Oracle SQL Developer query not sorting alphabetically

Tags: sql, oracle

My query:

```
SELECT 
    pmmr.REQUEST_NO, pmmr.item_code itemCode, Pmmr.Form_No Form_No, 
    NVL(Pmf.Form_Name, Pmmr.Form_No) formName, pmmr.MRN, 
    NVL(p.FIRST_NAME || DECODE(p.FAMILY_NAME, NULL, '', ' ' || p.FAMILY_NAME),pmmr.MRN) PATIENT_NAME,
    pmmr.ASSIGNED_TO, pmmr.DRUG_GENERIC_NAME, pmmr.LAST_STATUS, 
    NVL(initcap(( hr1.FIRST_NAME || ' ' ||  hr1.LAST_NAME)), pmmr.LAST_PERFORMER_ID) LastActionBy,
    NVL(hr2.DEPARTMENT || ' - ' || hr2.SECTION_NAME,'') ORGANIZATION_UNIT, 
    NVL(initcap(( hr2.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || hr2.LAST_NAME)), pmmr.REQUESTER_ID) RequesterName, 
    pmmr.REQUEST_DATE
FROM 
    inhouse_apps.PHRM_MFRP_MEDICATION_REQUEST pmmr
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    inhouse_apps.Hr_Employee hr1 ON Pmmr.Last_Performer_Id = Hr1.Employee_Number
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    inhouse_apps.Hr_Employee hr2 ON inhouse_apps.Pmmr.Requester_Id = Hr2.Employee_Number
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    EAPPTMT.PATIENT p ON inhouse_apps.Pmmr.Mrn = P.Mrn
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    inhouse_apps.Phrm_Mfrp_Form pmf ON Pmmr.Form_No = Pmf.Form_No;
WHERE 
    LAST_STATUS IN ('Approved')
    AND Pmmr.Form_No = 2
ORDER BY 
    pmmr.DRUG_GENERIC_NAME ASC
```

I need the `DRUG_GENERIC_NAME` sorted alphabetically, but it's not returning the result sorted ..

[image]

EDIT: as mentioned below the semicolon needed to be removed, that's all

Comment: Please tell me this is made up test data...

Comment: When you order by UPPER(pmmr.DRUG_GENERIC_NAME) what happens?

Comment: Seriously - if the content of this post is - as it appears - *actual* patient data, then you are most likely breaking dozens of privacy laws by posting it, no matter where you're from. Please confirm this is test data, or remove the image immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have semicolon ";" before your "Where clause". You need to remove it from there to make Oracle take account of both your "Where clause" and your "Order by clause"

```sql
SELECT pmmr.REQUEST_NO, pmmr.item_code itemCode, Pmmr.Form_No Form_No, nvl(Pmf.Form_Name, Pmmr.Form_No) formName, pmmr.MRN, nvl  (p.FIRST_NAME || DECODE(p.FAMILY_NAME, NULL, '', ' ' || p.FAMILY_NAME),pmmr.MRN)  PATIENT_NAME,pmmr.ASSIGNED_TO,
              pmmr.DRUG_GENERIC_NAME,pmmr.LAST_STATUS, nvl(initcap(( hr1.FIRST_NAME || ' ' ||  hr1.LAST_NAME)),pmmr.LAST_PERFORMER_ID) LastActionBy,
              nvl(hr2.DEPARTMENT || ' - ' || hr2.SECTION_NAME,'') ORGANIZATION_UNIT, nvl(initcap(( hr2.FIRST_NAME || ' ' || hr2.LAST_NAME)),pmmr.REQUESTER_ID) RequesterName, pmmr.REQUEST_DATE
              FROM inhouse_apps.PHRM_MFRP_MEDICATION_REQUEST pmmr
              left outer join inhouse_apps.Hr_Employee hr1 on Pmmr.Last_Performer_Id = Hr1.Employee_Number
              left outer join inhouse_apps.Hr_Employee hr2 on inhouse_apps.Pmmr.Requester_Id = Hr2.Employee_Number
              left outer join EAPPTMT.PATIENT p on inhouse_apps.Pmmr.Mrn = P.Mrn
              left outer join inhouse_apps.Phrm_Mfrp_Form pmf on Pmmr.Form_No = Pmf.Form_No
         WHERE LAST_STATUS IN ('Approved')
                  and Pmmr.Form_No = 2
          order by pmmr.DRUG_GENERIC_NAME ASC
          ;
```